# How to print multiple variables of different type to console in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I am a beginner in C++, after a few minutes of coding I got tired of manually typing 
"std:cout << "print something" << std:endl;" so I decided to create a function called printL to simplify printing to console, after a few hours and a few optimizations I ended up with a template and I attempted to create a variadic template but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code

```
template < typename T > void printL(T t){
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template < typename T, typename ...F > void printL(T t, F ...f) {

    std::cout << t << printL(f...) << std::flush;
}

int main() {
    printL("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ", "dog");

    return 0;
```

it should output this:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog dog
```

the code should take in a number of parameters that are unknown and the types are unknown as well. and it should print them in one line and end the print function with a new line.

Comment: If you're a true beginner, you probably shouldn't be playing with templates yet. That's not the easy way to learn. But anyway...

Comment: I mean I've programmed before on other languages just not C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is defined to return `void`, so your code will not work.
Instead, just print the first argument, then make a recursive call to print the rest.

```
std::cout << t;
printL(f...);
```

Your terminating implementation uses `std::endl`, and that already flushes.

Comment: thank you so much, I'm finding C++ harder than I had anticipated

Comment: @Rios Well, templates even trips up some advanced users some times. So what you're learning isn't the easy part of C++.

Comment: @Chipster yea thats true, tbh I went down a rabbit hole and I didn't want to give up or ask for help but oh well haha

Answer (score 4):

With C++17 [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), it's even simpler

```
template <typename... T> void printL(T... t) {
    (std::cout << ... << t) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to add the parentheses like this : `(std::cout << ... << t) << std::endl`. They are part of the fold expression.

Comment: Already upvoted, but I was trying to get this to work too, but couldn't figure out the syntax. I was trying `(<< ...t)`.